# multiple kableExtra::column_spec based on number of variables

Tags: r, dataframe, kableextra

I want to reproduce the figure below for a data frame with any number of columns (assuming all columns have same format)

For example, I have a data frame where each cell is a list containing numeric values

```
# dataframe containg data
df <- data.frame(YEAR = 1980:1990)  %>% 
  tibble::as_tibble()
vars <- c("a","b","c")

df["a"] <- list(list(rnorm(100)))
df["b"] <- list(list(rnorm(100)))
df["c"] <- list(list(rnorm(100)))
```

I then create a table

```
# dataframe to create for table
newdf <- data.frame(YEAR = 1980:1990) %>% 
  tibble::as_tibble()
newdf[vars] <- ""

# create table
kableExtra::kbl(newdf,
                          col.names=c("YEAR",vars),
                          caption=paste0("Title"),
                          escape=F) %>%
kableExtra::kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover")) %>%
kableExtra::column_spec(2,image=kableExtra::spec_hist(df$a)) %>%
kableExtra::column_spec(3,image=kableExtra::spec_hist(df$b)) %>%
kableExtra::column_spec(4,image=kableExtra::spec_hist(df$c))
```

It looks something like this:

[image]

This all works great.

However in reality i have a data frame that changes in the number of columns that need to be plotted by kableExtra (since it is created based on user inputs) and i can't work out how to achieve this since in the example above the `column_spec` function needs to be repeated for each column. So i need a way to generate the table for a variable data frame size.

This seems to be compounded by the use of the pipe operator.

I have looked at piping a function but i think the function still has the same problem of piping a variable number of sequential commands.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can simultaneously format multiple columns with a `purrr::reduce` statement, setting the `.init` argument to the table.  That way, the `column_spec` function can be applied to multiple columns in an elegant way.

The command call will be like

```
reduce(columns, column_spec, [column_spec arguments], .init = table)
```

The `reduce` will call `column_spec(table, columns[1], [column_spec arguments]`, then send that output (call it `modified_table`) to `column_spec(modeifed_table, columns[2], [column_spec arguments]`, etc.

Here's some example code.  Sorry - I tried to create a reprex but I can't get it to work with the html tables.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

df <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 1:10, c = 1:10)

which_col <- c("b", "c")  # which columns to format in the reduce()

df %>%
  kbl() %>%
  reduce(
    which(names(df) %in% which_col), # column_spec wants a vector of column indices
    column_spec,
    bold = TRUE, # this is a ... argument, which will get sent to column_spec
    .init = .
  )

# for more complex cases, won't be able to use ... argument as elegantly
df %>%
  kbl() %>%
  reduce(
    which(names(df) %in% which_col), 
    ~column_spec(.x, .y, bold = rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), 5)),
    .init = .
  )
```

edit: here is how this would be applied to your table

```r
library(kableExtra)

reduce_inputs <- lst(
  col = match(vars, names(newdf)), 
  dat = df[, vars]
) %>% 
  transpose() 

# create table
newdf %>%
  kbl(
    newdf,
    col.names = c("YEAR", vars),
    caption = paste0("Title"),
    escape= FALSE
  ) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover")) %>%
  reduce(
    reduce_inputs,
    ~column_spec(.x, .y$col, image = spec_hist(.y$dat)),
    .init = .
  )
```

Comment: Thanks. Not sure i can adapt this to my problem. not sure `reduce` is appropriate in this case. But will use it in future projects

Comment: Take a look at the new example on your table

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem for quite a while. One complication is that a lot of functions simply don't work on kableExtra objects. A possible solution, though not very elegant or R-like, is to simply write a loop.

Using the code from the example as a starter, and assuming an unknown number of columns:

```
# Dataframe containing data
df <- data.frame(YEAR = 1980:1990)  %>% 
  tibble::as_tibble()
vars <- c("a","b","c")

df["a"] <- list(list(rnorm(100)))
df["b"] <- list(list(rnorm(100)))
df["c"] <- list(list(rnorm(100)))

# Dataframe to create for table
newdf <- data.frame(YEAR = 1980:1990) %>% 
  tibble::as_tibble()
newdf[vars] <- ""


# Store table to be worked on
kable_out <- kableExtra::kbl(newdf,
                             col.names=c("YEAR",vars),
                             caption=paste0("Title"),
                             escape=F) %>%
  kableExtra::kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover"))


# Loop over columns for column_spec
for (col_num in 2:ncol(df)) {
  
  kable_out <- kableExtra::column_spec(kable_out,
                                       col_num,
                                       image=kableExtra::spec_hist(df[[col_num]]))
}

kable_out
```